# Get string out of url in calculated column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have column in sharepoint 2010 list which has value like
http://mysitecollection/sites/SPDev/Arizona/Lighthouse.jpg

I want the value in calculated column should be Arizona.
Can anyone let me know the formula for this manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated column and set the return type to Single line of text.

If the URL path until Arizona is constant, then add the below formula

```
=LEFT(RIGHT([Column Name],LEN([Column Name])-36),FIND("/",RIGHT([Column Name],LEN([Column Name])-36))-1)
```

Replace the column name and Number "36" based on the number of characters before the text "Arizona".

Answer (score 0):

If the sitename before the Statename is fixed you can get everything after SPDev/ with:

```
=MID( [Col] , FIND("SPDev/", [Col] )+6 , 255)
```

+6 is the length of SPDev/

You then have to get the string length up to the first **/** (after the Statename)

```
=FIND( "/" , MID( [Col] ,FIND("SPDev/", [Col] )+6,255) )-1
```

All together in one Formula:

```
=MID( [Col] ,FIND("SPDev/", [Col] )+6,FIND("/",MID( [Col] ,FIND("SPDev/", [Col] )+6,255))-1)
```